# Convert tf.extract_image_patches to batch shape

Tags: tensorflow

I batch together my data

```
batch_size = 50
min_after_dequeue = 100
capacity = min_after_dequeue + 3 * batch_size

mr_batch, us_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
      [mr, us], batch_size=batch_size, capacity=capacity,
      min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
mr_batch, us_batch
```

This gives me tensor shapes:

```
(<tf.Tensor 'shuffle_batch_2:0' shape=(50, 466, 394, 1) dtype=int16>,
 <tf.Tensor 'shuffle_batch_2:1' shape=(50, 366, 323, 1) dtype=uint8>)
```

Then I resize the image to have same resolution:

```
mr_batch = tf.image.resize_bilinear(mr_batch, [366, 323])
mr_batch, us_batch
```

Which gives me shapes:

```
(<tf.Tensor 'ResizeBilinear_13:0' shape=(50, 366, 323, 1) dtype=float32>,
 <tf.Tensor 'shuffle_batch_2:1' shape=(50, 366, 323, 1) dtype=uint8>)
```

Finally I extract image patches:

```
us_patch = tf.extract_image_patches(label, [1, 7, 7, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], 'SAME')
mr_patch = tf.extract_image_patches(image, [1, 7, 7, 1], [1, 2, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1], 'SAME')

us_patch, mr_patch
```

And have shape:

```
(<tf.Tensor 'ExtractImagePatches_8:0' shape=(50, 92, 81, 1225) dtype=uint8>,
 <tf.Tensor 'ExtractImagePatches_9:0' shape=(50, 92, 81, 1225) dtype=float32>)
```

I would now like to convert this shape to `(50*1225, 92, 81)` so I can feed it to my train step.

**How is this tensor operation called?**

Comment: Would `tf.reshape(us_patch, [-1, 92, 81])` work?

Comment: @OlivierMoindrot yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `tf.reshape` with the special argument `-1` to fill the remaining value:

```
tf.reshape(us_patch, [-1, 92, 81])
```

---

However, this can be dangerous because when you get the previous shapes wrong (for instance if `us_patch` has shape `[50, 92, 81, 1000]`), TensorFlow will not output an error and just reshape the whole thing to `[50*1000, 92, 81]`.